# python: delete non-empty dir

Tags: python, file

How do I delete a possibly non-empty dir in Python.

The directory may have nested subdirectories many levels deep.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Use [`shutil.rmtree`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree):

```
import shutil

shutil.rmtree(path)
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) for details of how to handle and/or ignore errors.

Answer (score 92):

The standard library includes [`shutil.rmtree`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) for this. By default,

```
shutil.rmtree(path)  # errors if dir not empty
```

will give `OSError: [Errno 66] Directory not empty: <your/path>`.

You can delete the directory and its contents anyway by ignoring the error:

```
shutil.rmtree(role_fs_path, ignore_errors=True)
```

You can perform more sophisticated error handling by also passing `onerrror=<some function(function, path, excinfo)>`.

Comment: `ignore_errors=True` means it does not remove the directory.

Comment: ignore_errors=True was the tickket

Comment: oh no, what a terrible name for parameter :(

Comment: shutil.rmtree(path) will not give errors if the directory is empty in python 3.8, so this probably changed since you posted 6 years ago. Just wanted to update for other people viewing this now.

Comment: `shutil.rmtree(path)` doesn't throw error if the directory not empty (python 3.7.9)

Answer (score 12):

You want [shutil.rmtree](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree)

> shutil.rmtree(path[, ignore_errors[,
> onerror]])
>
> Delete an entire directory
> tree; path must point to a directory
> (but not a symbolic link to a
> directory). If ignore_errors is true,
> errors resulting from failed removals
> will be ignored; if false or omitted,
> such errors are handled by calling a
> handler specified by onerror or, if
> that is omitted, they raise an
> exception.