# model_dir deletion in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

As part of an hyperparameter optimization routine, I use tensorflows high level api `tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor()`. The problem is that it creates for each instance an own new model_dir, which I can't delete for some reason during running the program (even after the model is overwritten and no longer in RAM). It is a problem because it consumes rather fast large amounts of disk storage. The question how can I delete the `model_dir`:

Here is some pseudo example:

```
import shutil
import tensorflow as tf

X = ... (some large input matrix)
y = ....(some large output vector)
for train, valid in KFoldCV(X, y):
    # res: dataframe of random hyper_parameters
    for idx, row in res.iterrows():
        print(row)

        x_1= tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x_1")
        x_2= tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("x_2")

        # DNN specification
        optimizer = tf.train.ProximalGradientDescentOptimizer(
                learning_rate=float(row['learning_rate']),
                l2_regularization_strength=float(row[
                    'l2_regularization_strength']))

        model = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(
                hidden_units=[int(row['hidden_units'])] * int(
                    row['layers']),
                feature_columns=[x_1, x_2],
                optimizer=optimizer,
                dropout=float(row['dropout']))

       model.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train[0], train[1]),
                      steps=step)
       res['loss']= model.evaluate(....)
       shutil.rmtree(model.model_dir)
```

The last statement raises the following error at first:

```
 OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty:
```

And if called a second time:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
```

EDIT:
it appears that TF event files allow for read-only during this process, some session in the backround blocking these files. Once I terminate the program, TF deletes these files by itself.

Comment: You need to use use `ignore_errors=True` parameter to `shutil.rmtree`. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21966211/3271168)

Comment: When `ignore_errors=True` the directory is not deleted, only the error ignored

Comment: It does look like you need to wait for all files to no longer be used before deleting the directory.